# how to combine a color detector and SSD detector for identifying a person?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I would like to combine a color detector and  SSD detector for identifying a person in real-time but I faced some issue when there are more than a person and more than one area for detected color, I don't know what is the reason?

**update:**
I knew the reason because of it calculates one box of the color area with boundary boxes of SSD detector and omitted others but I can't solve it

I used an Intersection over Union (IoU) to combine them and change in the equation to fit with my issue.

this is full my code:

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import cv2
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

global x1 , y1 , w1, h1, endX, startX, endY, startY , area1
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
w1 = 0
h1 = 0
endY = 0
endX = 0
startX = 0
startY = 0
area1 = 0

CLASSES = ["background", "aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat", "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable", "dog", "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep", "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"]
COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(CLASSES), 3))
print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe('prototxt.txt', 'caffemodel')
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")

vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2.0)
fps = FPS().start()
width = vs.get(3)  # float
height = vs.get(4)  # float
print width, height

fps = FPS().start()
while True:
    ret, frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
    #==============================================color detector==================
    detected_color = 0
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #black_color
    # green_lower = np.array([0, 0, 0], np.uint8)
    # green_upper = np.array([180, 255, 30], np.uint8)
    # black_red
    green_lower = np.array([136, 87, 111], np.uint8)
    green_upper = np.array([180, 255, 255], np.uint8)
    # green_lower = np.array([36, 25, 25], np.uint8)
    # green_upper = np.array([70, 255, 255], np.uint8)
    green = cv2.inRange(hsv, green_lower, green_upper)
    # Morphological Transform, Dilation
    kernal = np.ones((5, 5), "uint8")
    red = cv2.dilate(green, kernal)
    res_red = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=green)
    # Tracking blue
    (_, contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(green, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area1 = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if (area1 > 300):
            x1, y1, w1, h1 = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            img = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x1 + w1, y1 + h1), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, "green Colour", (x1, y1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 0, 0))
            detected_color = 1
    # ==============================================SSD detector==================
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)), 0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()
    big_area = 0
    big_center = 320
    detected = 0

    for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
        object_type = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
        if object_type == 15 and confidence > 0.2:
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
            label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format('person', confidence * 100)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), [0, 0, 255], 2)
            y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
            cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, [0, 0, 255], 2)
            # ==============================================IOU==================
            a = Polygon([(x1, y1 + h1), (x1 + w1, y1 + h1), (x1 + w1, y1), (x1, y1)])
            b = Polygon([(startX, endY), (endX, endY), (endX, startY), (startX, startY)])
            iou = (a.intersection(b).area / (a.area + 1))
            print iou
            # print 'a.area', a.area, 'hullArea', hullArea
            if detected_color:
                if iou >= 0.7:
                    # print iou
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), [0, 0, 0], 2)
                    y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
                    cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, [0, 0, 0], 2)
                else:
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), [0, 0, 255], 2)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
    fps.update()
    fps.stop()
vs.release()    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

data [caffemodel](https://github.com/jakelarsen17/TurtleBot-Follow-Person/blob/master/MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel), [prototxt.txt](https://github.com/jakelarsen17/TurtleBot-Follow-Person/blob/master/MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt), or [TurtleBot-Follow-Person](https://github.com/jakelarsen17/TurtleBot-Follow-Person)

the output:
first 1 (just SDD detector ) is OK for me:

[image: just SDD detector]

these figures(red color detector and   SDD detector for human detection) are OK for me so that area of color inside boundary box of human, this means `IOU = 1` , where I chose `IOU >= 0.7` in my code :

[image: red color detector and SDD detector] [image: red color detector and SDD detector] [image: red color detector and SDD detector]

this is a figure(red color detector and   SDD detector for human detection) is OK for me so that area of color outside boundary box of human, this means `IOU = 0`, where I chose `IOU >= 0.7` in my code :

[image: area of color outside boundary box of human]

all above not any issue for me, the issue if there are many areas of color like this figure,
you can see the right person is identified but left person is not identified, assume that it identify because there is an area of color in boundary box of human.

[image: many areas of color].

note:

the blue box is express color detection

the red box is express human detection

the black box is express combining them

I would like to identify all person when there is an area of color inside the boundary box of human whatever the number of people or the number of area of the color detector, it is enough to have one area inside each person to identify him/her.